# INGRESAR DATOS A MSQL DE UNA TABLA QUE NO EXISTA EN OTRA MYSQL

Tags: mysql

ESTOY INTANTADO HACER UNA CONSULTA DONDE INSERTE DATOS DE UNA TABLA, Y A AL VEZ ME CONSULTE LO QUE EXISTEN PARA ASI NO INSERTAR REPETIDOS. EN PALABRAS CORTAS, INSERTAR REGISTROS QUE NO EXISTAN, PARA NO DUPLICARLOS.

Tengo dos tablas con la misma estructura.
en express tengo datos de uso frecuente, y express1 es una tabla que uso para tomar esos datos y actualizar express. Pero en este caso necesito insertar los datos de express1 en express, pero solo no que no existan en la tabla de destino que es express.

LAS DOS TABLAS TIENEN LA MISMA ESTRUCTURA.

```
 INSERT INTO express 
      (id,cod_empresa,tipo,empresa,equipo,tarjeta,serie,idd,id_orden,
     id_actividad,identificacion,nombre_cliente, 
      direccion,localidad,codigo_postal,provincia,fecha_creacion,telefono1,
      telefono2,fecha_de_envio,cartera,baja,id_fecha_recolector,remito_rend,
      remito_cv,fecha_rend_cv,id_operador_ren,id_motivo_ren, 
       master_box,id_operador,id_motivo,tabla_oper,MULTIPLES,
       cable_hdmi,cable_av,fuente,control_1,email_enviado,otros,
        remito_sub,fecha_remito_sub,fecha_asignado,id_recolector,
        sub_asignado, ciclo,zona,fecha_premio,mes_base,R1, R2,R3, 
       operador,tipo_de_recupero,semanas,ano_semana,fecha_de_liquidacion,
       id_recolector_2,hist_pactados,
      estado_rechorario_rec,estado_pac,horario_pac,password_rec,emailcliente,
      adicional,otrosaccesorios,id_orden_pass,latitude,longitude,cod_search,url)
      
      SELECT  
     id,cod_empresa,tipo,empresa,equipo,tarjeta,serie,idd,id_orden,id_actividad,
  
      identificacion,nombre_cliente,direccion,localidad,
       codigo_postal,provincia,fecha_creacion,telefono1,
      telefono2,fecha_de_envio,cartera,baja,id_fecha_recolector,remito_rend,
      remito_cv,fecha_rend_cv,id_operador_ren,id_motivo_ren, 
      master_box,id_operador,id_motivo,tabla_oper,MULTIPLES,cable_hdmi,
      cable_av,fuente,control_1,email_enviado,otros,remito_sub,fecha_remito_sub,
       fecha_asignado,id_recolector,sub_asignado, 
       ciclo,zona,fecha_premio,mes_base,R1,
       R2,R3, operador,tipo_de_recupero,semanas,ano_semana,
       fecha_de_liquidacion,
       id_recolector_2,hist_pactados,
        estado_rechorario_rec,estado_pac,horario_pac,password_rec,emailcliente,
        adicional,otrosaccesorios,id_orden_pass,latitude,longitude,cod_search,url

       FROM express e
       INNER JOIN  express1 s
       ON e.id=s.id 
         WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM express
                 WHERE id = express1.id);
```

ESTA CONSULTA ME DICE COLIMN ID IN FIELD IS AMBIGUOS.

Comment: mas alla de que tu pregunta se entiende poco (usa el boton [edit], arreglala) si la columna es ambigua es porque forma parte de mas de una tabla del from y no sabe de donde tomarla. Agrega un alias a las tablas y poneselo y se soluciona.

Comment: si, pero quiero saber si la estructura de la consulta esta bien.

Comment: a que te referis con que la estructura esta bien?

Comment: si la consulta es valida.

Comment: y porque no seria valida? tu pregunta es ambigua, nos estas pidiendo que validemos una consulta (que parece que funciona) y no podemos, porque no tenemos nada de mas informacion mas que tu consulta. Si no tira error, esta bien, si tira error, esta mal...

Comment: No se entiende claro tu pregunta, pero podrias crear tablas temporales e insertar los datos ahí.

Comment: Quiero verificar es la sintaxis. el campo id, es el campo que tengo para compararlos